# ui-grid editableCellTemplate Textarea Edit Text

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

For one of the column cells I want to use Editable Text Area. 
Here is my snippet of the code.

```
    { field: 'Tasks', enableCellEdit: true, cellTooltip: true, headerTooltip: true, width: '50%' , enableFiltering: false,
          editableCellTemplate: '<textarea style="width:100%" ng-class="\'colt\' + col.index" ng-input="COL_FIELD" ng-model="COL_FIELD"></textarea>'},
```

But the textarea doesn't accept any change/edits. I believe there is an conflict with the model, can someone point me to the right direction.

Can someone explain how to do this?

All I want is an editable text area input for my cells.

Here is the Plunkr of my code http://plnkr.co/edit/Fpqsdthu4FhyUoD5gGcL?p=preview
Thanks,

Comment: Additionally, if I remove the ng-model="COL_FIELD" from the textarea,  I am able to edit, but the cell default value is blanked out.

Comment: In the example here https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-grid/wiki/Templating, this doesn't work for me.  editableCellTemplate: '<input type="number" ng-class="\'colt\' + col.index" ng-input="COL_FIELD" ng-model="COL_FIELD" />' } ]

Answer (score 2):

Based on the default template here:
https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-grid/blob/master/src/features/edit/templates/cellEditor.html

Try using the following for your template instead:

```html
<textarea ng-class="'colt' + col.uid" ui-grid-editor ng-model="MODEL_COL_FIELD"></textarea>
```

It seems the main problem with the template in the wiki is the use of the COL_FIELD for the ng-model.

Answer (score 2):

Add this to column config.

```
editableCellTemplate:
  `<div>
    <textarea ng-class="'colt' + col.uid" ui-grid-editor ng-model="MODEL_COL_FIELD"></textarea>
  </div>`
```

Answer (score 1):

> All I want is an editable text area input for my cells.

Then you should better use their provided features. [Editable](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/201_editable)

As you can see in the tutorial, there are also many callback function which you'll need to consider.

Here is the [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/4XglCNgupoEAZ2qgJl2P?p=preview) . The cellEdit you wrote and the actually edit function of ui-grid were conflicted i think.

ps: on the page in the first link, you can find out many callback function such as  `cellEditableCondition` and `afterCellEdit`

Comment: I have used the Editable feature as you can see in this Plunkr  http://plnkr.co/edit/Fpqsdthu4FhyUoD5gGcL?p=preview   but the textarea doesn't seem to work. Can you explain more on the "callback function"